# Apache rewrite map with two possibilities mapping to one URL?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've got to rewrite URLs that look like:
`/foo/bar/xyz/` to `/abc/`

But I've also got to rewrite slightly different URLs to the same destination, like this:
`/foo/xyz/` to `/abc/`

I've set up a map that looks like:
`xyz/ /abc/`

And rules like this:

```
RewriteMap rewrites txt:/path/to/rewritemap.txt
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foo/.*
RewriteRule ^/foo/(.*) ${rewrites:$1} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foo/bar/.*
RewriteRule ^/foo/bar/(.*) ${rewrites:$1} [R=301,L]
```

However, the second one (`foo/bar`) only works if I comment out the first one (`foo` only). I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here.

(The only solution I can think of is to have double the number of matching URLs in my map file, but that's inefficient)

Comment: Have you tried just changing the order from most specific to least specific?

Comment: Simple as that! Thanks - this is the correct answer, it works.

Comment: I'll add it as the answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache will process rewrite rules in an order of complexity so to speak. To get it to handle multiple patterns in the way you want you would add them in an order of most specific to least specific.

In your case you simply need to change the two conditions around in the configs:

```
RewriteMap rewrites txt:/path/to/rewritemap.txt

# Most specific first
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foo/bar/.*
RewriteRule ^/foo/bar/(.*) ${rewrites:$1} [R=301,L]

# Least specific (wildcard) last
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foo/.*
RewriteRule ^/foo/(.*) ${rewrites:$1} [R=301,L]
```